# Can't get attribute location pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, shader, pyglet, pyopengl, opengl-3

this code doesn't allow me to use it

```
 position_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position")
 color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "color")
```

the full code near it

```
 shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(self.vertex_shader_source, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                              OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(self.fragment_shader_source, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
                                              
    position_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position")
    color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "color")
                    
                                              
    glUseProgram(shader)
    
    vbo = GLuint(0)
    glGenBuffers(1, vbo)
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 72, (GLfloat * len(self.triangle))(* self.triangle), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
```

this is all the code aside from the shaders, which is in another question of mine. it works fine if i don't get the locations, but i was told i need to. if you could help me understand why it isn't working that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *name* argument needs to be a [Bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) ([bytesprefix `b`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-bytesprefix)) rather than a string:

<s>`position_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, 'position')`</s>
<s>`color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, 'color')`</s>

```py
position_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, b'position')
color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(shader, b'color')
```